Векторная графика в андроид студио
Возможно ли вообще программно обращаться к отдельным элементам path векторного изображения в андроид студио (kotlin)? Хочу сделать поочередно анимации на несколько group

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/drawable-animation#AnimVector

Вы саму Студию собираетесь анимировать, или все-таки Андроид приложение?
